# Latest Customer Donation And Amount

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

1. `Customer` which has an `Id` column representing the customer Id.
2. `CustomerDonation` that contains `CustomerId` (FK), `Amount` and `DatePayed`

I'd like have all the customers together with their latest donation and the amount of that donation.

I am receiving duplicate values on my query so I will not paste it here.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?  You should ***still*** paste your query here.  It may only need a slight change and we can better explain the issue.  Or it may even indicate some useful information not otherwise mentioned.  If you have "almost working" code, you should *always* include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH
   SortedDonation AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY DatePayed DESC)  AS SeqID,
        *
    FROM
       CustomerDonation
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Customer
LEFT JOIN
    SortedDonation
        ON  SortedDonation.CustomerId = Customer.Id
        AND SortedDonation.SeqId      = 1
```

If the same customer can make multiple donations with the same `DatePayed`, then this will arbitrarily pick just one of them.

If you add additional fields to the `ORDER BY` you can deterministically pick which one you want.

Or, if you want all of them use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the WITH TIES option

```
 Select Top 1 With Ties *
  From  YourTable
  Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By CustomerId Order By DatePayed Desc)
```

Comment: Very nice, shorter code and no extra fields incidentally created :)

Comment: I never thought of this. :D

Comment: @DVT I say/think that every day.   That's why I love SO so much

Comment: Definitely like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Row_Number() Analytic function .

```
Select * from (
   Select customerId,Amount,DatePayed, row_number() over (partition by CustomerId order by DatePayed desc) as rowN) 
   as tab where rowN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need the `CustomerDonation` table for this. You can join with the `Customer` table if you want other information of the customer.

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
    CustomerId
    , MAX(DatePayed) AS LastDate
FROM
    CustomerDonation
)
SELECT
    cd.CustomerId
    , cd.Amount
    , cd.DatePayed
FROM
    CustomerDonation cd
    JOIN cte ON cd.CustomerId = cte.CustomerId
        AND cd.DatePayed = cte.LastDate
```